# Knockout binding issue on partial view

Tags: knockout.js

I've created a partial view that I can include in other views for handling notifications.

```
<div id="notifications">
    <!-- ko with: $root.currentNotification -->
    <span data-bind="text: notificationType"></span>
    <span data-bind="text: friendlyMessage"></span>
    <!-- ko if: $root.technicalMessageShown -->
    <span data-bind="text: technicalMessage"></span>
    <!-- /ko -->
    <button data-bind="click: $root.toggleTechnicalMessage, text: $root.technicalMessageButtonText"></button>
    <button data-bind="click: $root.dismissNotification">Dismiss</button>
    <!-- /ko -->

    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>

</div>
```

The view is bound to the view model using the following binding in the parent view.

```
var notificationsViewModel = new NotificationsViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(notificationsViewModel, document.getElementById("notifications"));
var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

When rendered, the elements inside of 'ko with: $root.currentNotification' aren't included in the DOM even though the currentNotification is present on the view model.

View Model displayed from last line in the partial view:

```
{
  "allNotifications": [
    {
      "id": "0",
      "notificationType": "Error",
      "friendlyMessage": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
      "technicalMessage": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque elit nulla, porta ac condimentum in, condimentum sed dui. Aliquam interdum."
    }
  ],
  "currentNotification": {
    "id": "0",
    "notificationType": "Error",
    "friendlyMessage": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.",
    "technicalMessage": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque elit nulla, porta ac condimentum in, condimentum sed dui. Aliquam interdum."
  },
  "technicalMessageButtonText": "More Info"
}
```

Any idea why knockout isn't seeing the current notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to target both bindings, if you only target the binding of one, the other will overwrite it.